# Update second sqlite database from first database

Tags: sqlite, database-backups

I have database A which gets new data every second day. Now I have a second database B, which is a duplicate of database A, which is stored on a different server for read access.

What I do at the moment is, I copy the whole Database A via rsync to replace database B. This is no problem in regards to locking and reading, because I know exactly when =the writing into A has finished. Also no problem concerning access to B.

Now A is getting quite large, and the copying becomes unreliable because of network errors so that I regularly have to copy the database a second time.

Is there a way (I am sure there is) to let sqlite do the updating of B? I have seen `.clone`, but, again, it would transfer a large amount of data, when only a small amount has changed.

Any suggestions, on how I can make the process of adding the new data added to A to B at a later time more efficient (using sqlite3)?

Comment: What you're looking for is "replication". While there are many tools to do [replication with SQLite](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=sqlite+leader+follower&ia=web), you may have outgrown SQLite.

Comment: Thanks - looked at the options and they sound like quite a bit of an overhang for this research program.